# learndash LMS Plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have add 10 question in my **quiz** (admin side) but only show 5 question user side in  using learndash LMS Plugin for wordpress. please give me Solution.

I have Using This Plugin

http://www.learndash.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you **edit the quiz** and scroll down, you will see lots of options in it. There is an option called **"Show only specific number of questions"**, make sure its **unchecked**.